# Kendo ui pie chart click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui

Does anyone know how to create an on-click event for the Kendo-UI data viz pie charts?

I want to get the template information of the clicked part.

This is the kendo code specified:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ScreenResolutionRemoteDataViewModel>()
            .Name("chart" + year)
            .Title(year)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "small-chart" })
            .Legend(legend => legend
                .Visible(false)
            )
            .DataSource(ds =>
            {
                ds.Read(read => read.Action("_SpainElectricityProduction", "Pie_Charts"));
                ds.Filter(filter => filter.Add(model => model.Year).IsEqualTo(year));
                ds.Sort(sort => sort.Add(model => model.Year).Ascending());
            }
            )
            .Series(series => series
                    .Pie(model => model.Share, model => model.Resolution, model => model.Color)
                    .Padding(0)
            )
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Format("{0:N0}")
                .Template("#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#")
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart control provides events. For your purposes, use the SeriesClick event. In MVC it can be used like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ScreenResolutionRemoteDataViewModel>()
  .Events(events => events
    .SeriesClick("onSeriesClick")
  )

function onSeriesClick(e) {
    kendoConsole.log(kendo.format("Series click :: {0} ({1}): {2}",
        e.series.name, e.category, e.value));
}
```

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/chart-api/events